# What is written in one file write to another

Tags: perl

I have one file, and I need everything that is written in some time frame to that file to be written to a second file.

What is the best way to do so? Open some thread that will read the file and do so ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: do you need to monitor a file for updates and extract the updates periodically, is that what you mean? like a log-watcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) utility might be what you're looking for:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @files = qw/ file1 file2 /;

open my $fh, "| tee @files >/dev/null"
  or die "$0: start tee failed: $!";

print $fh "$_\n" for map int rand 10, 1 .. 5;

close $fh or warn "$0: close tee: $!";
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./write-both

$ cat file1
0
7
5
8
2

$ cat file2
0
7
5
8
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [`tail -f`](http://ss64.com/bash/tail.html) or the [poor man's `tail -f` emulation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#seek).

Answer (score -3):

Sounds like a job for [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Copy)